# Formula for a periodic sequence of 1s and -1s with period 5

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been playing with periodic sequences of 1s and -1s lately. This is what I came up with:
\begin{eqnarray*}
-(-1)^n& = &1, -1, 1, -1,\ldots\quad\textrm{(Period 2)}\\
\left(-(-1)^n\right)^{\frac{n+2}{2}} & = &1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1,\ldots\quad\textrm{(Period 4)}\\
 \left(\left(-(-1)^n\right)^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\right)^{\frac{n+4}{4}}& = &1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, \ldots\quad\textrm{(Period 8)}
\end{eqnarray*}
One can easily find a similar formula for a periodic sequence with period $ 2^n, n\in\mathbb{N} $.
I also found a formula:
$$
(-1)^{2 \sin\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{6}\right)},
$$
which gives a sequence $ -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1,\ldots $ with period 3.

**My question is: Is there a formula for a periodic sequence of 1s and -1s with period 5? If there is, what is it?**

I know about this formula for a periodic zero and one sequence with period $ N $:
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^N\cos\left(-2\pi\frac{n(k-1)}{N}\right)/N = 0, 0, 0, \ldots, 1.
$$
However, it requires to sum up $ N $ expressions to count the $ n\textrm{th} $ term, which is why I don't like it. **I would also like the formula not to contain functions like floor or modulus.**

Comment: Wouldn't at this point the more natural question be finding a formula with period $3$ without using an "advanced" function like the sine?

Comment: Also, must the formula with a period $n$ produce $n-1$ positive 1's followed by a single negative 1 before the pattern repeats?

Comment: @GDumphart I thought about this too, but I don't think it exists. "Less advanced" functions (polynomials) give a sequence of even and odd numbers with period $ 2^n $, don't they?

Comment: @teadawg1337 Not necassarily. It can by any sequence of positive and negative 1's with period 5.

Comment: In that case, my topic [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033953/defining-a-perplexing-two-dimensional-sequence-explicitly) gives two different examples with period 4. Perhaps that can help get the ball rolling

Comment: Dirichlet characters?

Comment: @daniel Too advanced for me (I'm still at highschool). But I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{4\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}5\right)+4\cos\left(\frac{4\pi k}5\right)-3}5=
\left\{\begin{array}{}
-1&\text{if }k\not\equiv0\pmod5\\
+1&\text{if }k\equiv0\pmod5\\
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}
$$

---

**Explanation**

The roots of $z^5-1$ are $z=e^{2\pi ik/5}$ for $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. [Vieta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) says that the coefficient of $z^4$ in $z^5-1$ the sum of the roots of $z^5-1$. That is, the sum of the roots is $0$. Taking the real part of the roots yields
$$
1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}5\right)+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}5\right)+\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}5\right)+\cos\left(\frac{8\pi}5\right)=0\tag{2}
$$
When $k\not\equiv0\pmod5$, $k$ is invertible $\bmod5$. Therefore,
$$
\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}5\right),\cos\left(\frac{4\pi k}5\right),\cos\left(\frac{6\pi k}5\right),\cos\left(\frac{8\pi k}5\right)\right)\tag{3}
$$
is a permutation of
$$
\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}5\right),\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}5\right),\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}5\right),\cos\left(\frac{8\pi}5\right)\right)\tag{4}
$$
Therefore,
$$
1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}5\right)+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi k}5\right)+\cos\left(\frac{6\pi k}5\right)+\cos\left(\frac{8\pi k}5\right)=0\tag{5}
$$
when $k\not\equiv0\pmod5$. When $k\equiv0\pmod5$,
$$
1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}5\right)+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi k}5\right)+\cos\left(\frac{6\pi k}5\right)+\cos\left(\frac{8\pi k}5\right)=5\tag{6}
$$
Since $\cos(x)$ is an even function with period $2\pi$, $(5)$ and $(6)$ become
$$
1+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}5\right)+2\cos\left(\frac{4\pi k}5\right)
=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{if }k\not\equiv0\pmod5\\
5&\text{if }k\equiv0\pmod5\\
\end{array}\right.\tag{7}
$$
Equation $(1)$ is simply a scaled and translated version of $(7)$.

Comment: I will continue to think on this.

Comment: Thank you! But why do $ \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{5}\right) $ and $ \cos\left(\frac{4\pi k}{5}\right) $ sum up so nicely?

Comment: @Mikulas: I have added an explanation of that.

Comment: You probably want $=-1$ in (1) to make it an equation.  Well done

Comment: @RossMillikan: thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, [you can use](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848384/4781) ***Fibonacci numbers*** and its generalizations for periods $3,4,5,\dots$

**Period 3.** Fibonacci numbers $F_n= 1, 1,  \color{blue}2, 3, 5,  \color{blue}8, 13, 21,  \color{blue}{34},\dots$

$$A_n = -(-1)^{F_n}=1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1,\dots$$

**Period 4.** Tribonacci numbers $T_n = 1, 1,  \color{blue}{2, 4}, 7, 13,  \color{blue}{24, 44}, 81, 149,  \color{blue}{274, 504},\dots$

$$B_n = -(-1)^{T_n}=1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1\dots$$

**Period 5.** Tetranacci numbers $W_n = 1, 1, 1, 1, \color{blue}4, 7, 13, 25, 49,  \color{blue}{94}, 181, 349, 673, 1297, \color{blue}{2500},\dots$

$$C_n = -(-1)^{W_n}=1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1,\dots$$

and so on.

Comment: Nice approach, +1

Comment: A closed-form for the tribonacci numbers in terms of binomial coefficients can be [found here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696201/what-is-a-mathematical-expression-for-the-sequence-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-dots).

Answer (score -1):

This is close:

${|\cos{\frac{\pi*x}{5}-\frac{\pi}{2}}|}^{0.0001}$

Comment: Your formula gives just numbers close to 1.

Comment: @Mikulas , I know, that's the problem, that's why I said it was close